# ruby double question mark

Tags: ruby

I came across this piece of ruby code:

```
str[-1]==??
```

What is the double question mark all about? Never seen that before.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Ruby 1.8** has a ?-prefix syntax that turns a character into its ASCII code value.  For example, `?a` is the ASCII value for the letter `a` (or 97).  The double question mark you see is really just the number `63` (or the ASCII value for `?`).

```
?a    # => 97
?b    # => 98
?c    # => 99
?\n   # => 10
??    # => 63
```

To convert back, you can use the `chr` method:

```
97.chr   # => "a"
10.chr   # => "\n"
63.chr   # => "?"

??.chr   # => "?"
```

In **Ruby 1.9**, the `?a` syntax returns the character itself (as does the square bracket syntax on strings):

```
??           # => "?"

"What?"[-1]  # => "?"
```

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the `?` syntax is deprecated in 1.9, seeing as it serves little purpose now?

Comment: Myrddin, That's probably a fair thing to say.  I don't see much point in using `?` syntax in 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

As Ryan says, the `?` prefix gives you the ASCII value of a character. The reason why this is useful in this context is that when you use the index notation on a string in Ruby 1.8 the ASCII value is returned rather than the character. e.g.

```
irb(main):009:0> str = 'hello'
=> "hello"
irb(main):010:0> str[-1]
=> 111
```

so the following wouldn't test if the last character of a string was the letter 'o'

```
irb(main):011:0> str[-1] == 'o'
=> false
```

but this would:

```
irb(main):012:0> str[-1] == ?o
=> true
```

and (provided you know what the ? does!) this is slightly clearer than

```
irb(main):013:0> str[-1] == 111
=> true
```

Comment: The above applies for Ruby 1.8, not 1.9 where `"hello"[-1] == "o"`

Comment: This is exactly the reason why, in ruby19, that `?o == "o"`, so that `"hello"[-1] == ?o` in both ruby18 and ruby19.

Comment: Thanks glenn, I've updated the answer to clarify the bit that only applies in 1.8